# foreign key column is being inserted null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been scratching my head for more than an hour and being unable to find solutions. i have two entities classes. one of them being Questions.java and other being Answers.java

**Question.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Questions {
@Id
@Column(name = "ques_id")
private  int ques_id;

@Column(name = "question")
private String question;

@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "param")
private String param;

@Column(name = "maxlength")
private int maxlength;

@Column(name = "dependency")
private String dependency;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "questions",targetEntity = Answers.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Answers> answers = new ArrayList<>();

public int getQues_id() {
    return ques_id;
}

public void setQues_id(int ques_id) {
    this.ques_id = ques_id;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getParam() {
    return param;
}

public void setParam(String param) {
    this.param = param;
}

public int getMaxlength() {
    return maxlength;
}

public void setMaxlength(int maxlength) {
    this.maxlength = maxlength;
}

public String getDependency() {
    return dependency;
}

public List<Answers> getAnswers() {
    return answers;
}

public void setAnswers(List<Answers> answers) {
    this.answers = answers;
}

public void setDependency(String dependency) {
    this.dependency = dependency;
}
}
```

**Answers.java**

```
@Entity
public class Answers {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "ans_label")
private String ans_label;

@Column(name = "ans_value")
private int ans_value;

@Column(name = "ans_weightage")
private int ans_weightage;

@Column(name = "is_default")
private int is_default;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ques_id")
private Questions questions;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAns_label() {
    return ans_label;
}

public void setAns_label(String ans_label) {
    this.ans_label = ans_label;
}

public int getAns_value() {
    return ans_value;
}

public void setAns_value(int ans_value) {
    this.ans_value = ans_value;
}

public int getAns_weightage() {
    return ans_weightage;
}

public void setAns_weightage(int ans_weightage) {
    this.ans_weightage = ans_weightage;
}

public int getIs_default() {
    return is_default;
}

public void setIs_default(int is_default) {
    this.is_default = is_default;
}

public Questions getQuestions() {
    return questions;
}

public void setQuestions(Questions questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
}
}
```

**SaveApiController.java**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveData(@RequestBody Questions questionss){
    //questions.setAnswers(questionss.getAnswers());

    saveQuestions.save(questionss);

}
```

The json data i am sending from postman looks like this.

```
  {
"id": "31",
"question": "३. लिङ्ग ?",
"type": "input_spinner",
"description": null,
"param": "",
"maxlength": "0",
"dependency": null,
      "answers": [
        {
          "ans_label": "पुरुष",
          "ans_value": "1",
          "ans_weightage": "0",
          "is_default": "0"
        },
        {
          "ans_label": "महिला",
          "ans_value": "2",
          "ans_weightage": "0",
          "is_default": "0"
        },
        {
          "ans_label": "अन्य",
          "ans_value": "3",
          "ans_weightage": "0",
          "is_default": "0"
        }
      ]
   }
```

Questions and answers data are all being stored apart from foreign key column in answers table. the column "ques_id" is being stored as NULL.

Answer (score -1):

One of the things that you have to keep in mind is that in order for the persistence provider to Cascade the save operation, you have to set the dependencies on both sides of the relationship..

So `Quesions` need to have a list of `Answers` and each of those answers need to have reference to the `Questions` entity. Only then the cascade will happen.

Not sure if this is the answer to your problem but give it a try.

Comment: well i think i have reference on both side. 

i have annotated OnetoMany on Questions entity and ManyToOne in Answers entity. isn't that enough to create relationship?